# Acoustic notifications in ThingsBoard?

Tags: audio, notifications, thingsboard

We intend to use ThingsBoard to visualize some objects' state, i.e. showing device faults or exceeding parameter thresholds. When an alarm condition is met, it would be desirable to have the UI play an acoustic notification.
Is there any way to implement this on "user/admin side" with the given software (for example by using HTML/JavaScript in contrast to changing the Java sources and rebuilding ThingsBoard itself) ?

Comment: You can use audio elements etc on dashboard widgets.

Comment: @lupz That's what I meant with "by using HTML". Do you have any hint/example/link how to do so?